# ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object HELP

Tags: база-данных, oracle

не могу найти ошибку

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
  st_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
  student_name VARCHAR(20),
  student_surname VARCHAR(20),
  student_email VARCHAR(20),
  CONSTRAINT student_id PRIMARY KEY (st_id),
  CONSTRAINT faculty FOREIGN KEY (faculty_id) REFERENCES faculty(faculty_id)
);
CREATE TABLE faculty(
  facul_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
  faculty_name VARCHAR(30),
  CONSTRAINT faculty_id1 PRIMARY KEY (facul_id)
);
```

Comment: У вас в БД уже есть объект с именем Student и скорее всего это таблица

Comment: Нашли?  `select object_name from all_objects where object_name in ('STUDENT','FACULTY');`.И ешё `faculty_id` и`facul_id ` должны совпадать.